# PHP TesseractOCR works only in command line

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I have set up TesseractOCR for php on my linux server. When i execute code from command line the image gets recognized but i get blank page when i run the same script from web browser.

Any idea how to make this work on web browser also ?

Comment: Check your webserver logs. Probably permissions or missing modules. Also enable error reporting & displaying

Comment: I get this error: file_get_contents(./my-temp-dir/231903195.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/ocr/TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.php on line 236

Comment: There's your problem then. Never used tesseract so don't know how to fix it, but it's probably a config setting, or you could try creating my-temp-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more than 10 hrs effort i fixed by doint these steps:

This is what i did.

1. Created a new directory inside var/www/html dir set  root and www as owner of the dir.
2. Copied all app files to the new dir and again set the ownership of each file and dir to www and root
3. chmod  775 temp-dir, chmod 775  TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.php
4. Added this code

$path = getenv('PATH');
putenv("PATH=$path:/usr/local/bin");

right after

require_once "TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.php";

Thanks

Comment: Hi I have followed your solution but didn't work . can you explain of this line in more detail "ownership of each file and dir to www and root" .
It is very urgent for me . I am awaiting your reply ..

Comment: Hi the issue is all related with directory permissions, you need to set the right permissions to all directories and assign them to the right user group.

Comment: I have already given the right missioner .. by the way i have successfully installed on another server.. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Only one things to do. Need to set environment variable.

> **For Example : PATH=$path:/usr/local/bin**